# Does Unairu's Sundering Dash Stack?

Tags: warframe

Does Sundering Dash stack? As in, could I get it at rank 0 and dash through an enemy 10 times to fully remove their armor like Oberon's HallowedGround + Reckoning combo?

Or maybe it stacks like Corrosive status procs, where it's 10% of current value each time, seeing vastly diminished returns but still eventually removing all armor?

...or does it not stack at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that it stacks the same way Corrosive does, reducing the current armor rather than the base armor.

Against a level 100 Grineer Heavy Gunner, it took just short of 80 dashes with base rank to fully remove her armor, down to a red health bar.